# Display 2 levels deep in WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently running this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'  => 1,
    'post_parent'     => 1743,      
    'meta_query'      => array(
        array(
            'key'      => 'sticky',
            'value'    => '1',
            'compare'  => '=='
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I have pages nested 2 deep in the post_parent but it only pulls one level deep. Any way of extending it to subpages down below the immediate children?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but it should work: While you're in the Loop, for each of the 2nd-tier posts (i.e., direct children, which you are currently able to reach) capture the current post ID  like so

```
$level2_parent_ID = $post->ID;
```

Then use WP_Query to start a query within the query, using $sub_parent_ID as the value for post_parent.  This should pull up children of the children.

As an example, to continue where you left off...

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            $level2_parent_ID = $post->ID;
            $level2_args = array(
                'post_type'       => 'page',
                'posts_per_page'  => 1,
                'post_parent'     => $level2_parent_ID,      
                'meta_query'      => array(
                    array(
                        'key'      => 'sticky',
                        'value'    => '1',
                        'compare'  => '=='
                    )
                )
            );

            $level2_query = new WP_Query($level2_args);
            // The Loop-within-a-loop
                if ( $level2_query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $level2_query->have_posts() ) {
                $level2_query->the_post();
                echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
                }
                }
            //plus whatever else you want to do in the outer loop
    }
} 
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```